# SQL LIKE partial match from string

Tags: php, sql, search, sql-like

I need do searching from longer string. In sql in **locality** is 'London' and i need use LIKE and string of more cities how in example.. 
This doesnt work.
Please help me, thanks

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM automoto WHERE (title LIKE '%$keyword%') AND locality LIKE '%London%Paris%' ");
```

Comment: how to write string of cities?

Comment: Use `OR`: `(title LIKE '%$keyword%') AND (locality LIKE '%London%' OR locality LIKE '%Paris%')`

Comment: This is pretty standard practice here. You may find you need to loop your words in PHP to assemble the query string too.

Comment: Thanks, and any nicer solution? Isnt possible to rewrite %London%Paris% to working shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable way would be to use one `OR` per city:

```
(title LIKE '%$keyword%') AND (locality LIKE '%London%' OR locality LIKE '%Paris%')
```

if you do not want to build up all these "or"-conditions, you could use a regex to match:

```
(title LIKE '%$keyword%') AND locality REGEXP '(London|Paris)'
```

Comment: Have read that REGEXP searches can take arbitrary time and memory space. If that is indeed true, in spite of it's elegance (& legibility), the former may be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Build up a string containing each city in an OR:

```
SELECT * FROM automoto WHERE title LIKE '%$keyword%' AND (locality LIKE '%London%' OR  locality LIKE '%Paris%')
```